# slice image based on horizontal lines

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

Hope someone can help me on this or just to confirm if this is actually doable or not.

I've a PNG file that has horizontal lines. I'd like to split the image into smaller files based on these lines.
How can I achieve this? Is this possible using imageMagick? Or from any other application for that matter that would allow it be automatic and batch processable.

I'm attaching the files as well so that it is more clear.

Thanks

Original file:
[image]

Sliced Part 1:
[image]

Sliced Part 2:
[image]

Sliced Part 3:
[image]

Sliced Part 4:
[image]

Comment: also, the line is put manually so if there is a requirement to have it with a specific size or color that could be met.

Comment: It should be quite do-able! You'd probably be making life easiest if you can use Linux or macOS rather than Windows, and if you can be sure to always use the same colour and make the line certain to cover the full width of the document and save the document as PNG rather than JPEG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
w=$(identify -ping -format '%[width]' green_lines.png)
h=$(identify -ping -format '%[height]' green_lines.png)
convert green_lines.png -resize 1x"${h}"\! -resize "${w}"x"${h}"\! out_green.png
convert out_green.png -colorspace HSV -channel S -separate  out_greenS.png
convert out_greenS.png -threshold 50% -negate out_greenS.png

convert out_greenS.png -define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=500000 \
-connected-components 8 objects.png| awk '{print $2}'|tail -n +2 >coodr.txt
i=0
while read size
do 
convert green_lines.png -crop "${size}"  crop_"${i}".png
i=$((i+1))
done < coodr.txt
```

Comment: I understand that my code is bad, I'm sorry. But it works. I ran it in windows 10 in cigwin64. The number of connected components in this case is not important.  I would like to see a good solution to this issue..

Comment: We are all here to learn - well, that's my intention at least. Let's see what comes up

Comment: Thank you @AlexAlex
I hope this question is useful to a lot of others as well.